# How do you order a list of sets such that sets with common elements are as far as possible from each other?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, set, set-intersection

Basically a problem I've been thinking about for the past couple weeks...

Initially thought of making each set in the list a node in a graph, and connecting nodes which do not have any common elements. I'd run a Hamilton path algorithm that only moves to the next node if the last k nodes don't contain a common element, however this seems really, really slow due to the nature of the Hamilton path algorithm. Would anyone else have any better ideas?

The restrictions for the variables is that each set can have around 1-40 elements, and the number of sets in the list would up to 40 maximum.

Comment: *"however this seems really, really slow"* << What sizes were the sets that you tried this with?

Comment: Do you care how many common elements a pair of sets has, or just that it has common elements? How many sets are there, and how many pairs of sets have common elements?

Comment: Do you care about the average distance between sets with common elements, or the min distance between sets with common elements, or something else?

Comment: @Dave I want the average distance between sets to be as maximal as possible :) Answering your other question, if any two sets contain ANY common elements, even just ONE, they should be separated.

Comment: @Stef In my application, the sizes of the sets can range from 1-40, and the largest number of sets I'd be using in practice would be at most 40 as well. I reckon checking for set intersections won't take too much time, but generating an optimal ordering is the real issue.